# Payflow Link silent post url

Tags: paypal, payflowpro, payflowlink

I have a silent post url set up.  I know that my code for the silent post url works in that if i send a form with information to this url, it carries out the instructions I have set for it -- waiting to receive silent post from Paypal when someone makes a payment.

The customer for whom i am working has a separate processor - not Paypal.  They use the Payflow link as a gateway only.

In spite of having the silent post url set up, we're not getting anything back from Paypal when someone makes a payment.  Is it because Paypal is not the processor, or is there some other reason maybe?

Comment: It should work fine regardless of the processor.  Have you checked your web server logs to ensure it's not actually getting hit but failing for some reason/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out why it wasn't working.  The host had shut of TLS 1.0 months ago.  Paypal (and maybe other services) still uses TLS 1.0.  Once the host was made aware of this, they set up a workaround for me.  There wasn't any error message on my server because the messages sent from paypal never got through.  The initial handshake that they tried to send via TLS 1.0 failed, so the rest of the information was never attempted.